# Como criar um teste com RSpec para verificar o retorno de usuários?

Tags: ruby, testes, tdd, rspec

Esse `describe` abaixo é o *default* que o Rspec cria. Tenho muita dificuldade em trabalhar com TDD ([Test Driven Development](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development)) e é complicado entender todo o procedimento. Por exemplo, eu preciso testar que, ao acessar o método `index`, seja retornado uma lista de usuários no formato JSON. Qual seria a forma para implementar o teste para esta funcionalidade?

```ruby
describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "returns http success" do
    get 'index'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

Comment: O que exatamente é a lista de usuários que você espera? Um documento JSON/XML? Uma página HTML com layouts?

Comment: Eu pensei em um objeto Json. O retorno seria um objeto Json.

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Por exemplo, meu método deverá retornar um JSON neste formato: `{'name': 'Luiz Picolo', 'account': '123456789'}`. Claro que o conteúdo de cada atributo não seria fixo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumindo que o resultado seja no formato JSON, como uma lista de objetos, cada um representando um usuário, exemplo:

```json
[{"nome": "João", "idade": 26}, {"nome": "Maria", "idade": 19}]
```

Você pode obter o corpo da resposta com `response.body`, ler o documento JSON e verificar o formato dele. Algo similar a isso:

```ruby
describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "returns a valid list of users" do
    get 'index'
    expect(response).to be_success

    # processar o JSON e se certificar de que é válido
    doc = nil
    expect {doc = JSON.parse(response.body)}.not_to raise_error(JSON::ParserError)

    # é uma lista
    expect(doc).to be_kind_of(Array)

    # onde cada elemento da lista...
    doc.each do |user|
      # é um objeto
      expect(user).to be_kind_of(Hash)

      # com "nome" e "idade"
      expect(user).to have_key("nome")
      expect(user).to have_key("idade")

      # sendo uma string e um inteiro
      expect(user["nome"]).to be_kind_of(String)
      expect(user["idade"]).to be_kind_of(Integer)
    end
  end
end
```

Depende do quão exato e restrito você quer o seu teste. Você pode ainda checar coisas como se as idades são positivas, ou se existem outras *keys* além das *"nome"* e *"idade"*.

Veja mais detalhes na [lista de *expectations*](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers).

Comment: Neste caso ele retorna todo o conteúdo, até com o render da página. Como eu pegaria apenas o retorno puro do método. Apenas o JSON?

Comment: Depende.. Você pode extrair com uma regex talvez. Difícil dizer qualquer coisa sem ver.

Answer (score 0):

Sua action index:

```
def index
   @users = User.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render json: @users }
   end
end
```

Você pode testar quantos usuários sua variável está retornando:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "retorna uma lista de usuários" do
    user1 = User.create(:nome=>"Maria", :idade=>"19")
    user2 = User.create(:nome=>"João", :idade=>"26")

    get 'index'
    assigns(@users).size.should == 2
  end
end
```